# Meteor : ELEMENT_OPERATORS.$in.compileElementSelector

Tags: meteor

```
"Exception in template helper: ELEMENT_OPERATORS.$in.compileElementSelector@http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo.js?e8806aa7782b729b2517ebc0cd10b321667f1427:1887:1
operatorBranchedMatcher/<@http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo.js?e8806aa7782b729b2517ebc0cd10b321667f1427:1569:1
_.forEach@http://localhost:3000/packages/underscore.js?0a80a8623e1b40b5df5a05582f288ddd586eaa18:164:13
operatorBranchedMatcher@http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo.js?e8806aa7782b729b2517ebc0cd10b321667f1427:1549:3
compileValueSelector@http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo.js?e8806aa7782b729b2517ebc0cd10b321667f1427:1453:12
compileDocumentSelector/<@http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo.js?e8806aa7782b729b2517ebc0cd10b321667f1427:1432:9
_.forEach@http://localhost:3000/packages/underscore.js?0a80a8623e1b40b5df5a05582f288ddd586eaa18:164:13
compileDocumentSelector@http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo.js?e8806aa7782b729b2517ebc0cd10b321667f1427:1415:3
._compileSelector@http://localhost:3000/packa"[…] meteor.js:887
```

Helper:

```
return WorkClassification.find({_id : {$in: this.classifications }});
```

But it returns correct data. I am seeing above exception in console. But it works. What caused that exception?

Answer (score 1):

I just have the same error in my meteor application. Extrapolating your example to mine, the problem was produced due to that *this.classifications* was *undefined* and **$in expects the value to be and array**. It can happen when classifications array have never been initialized with an empty array (it is absolutely not required).

```
if (!this.classifications || !classifications.length) return [];
return WorkClassification.find({
    _id : {
        $in: this.classifications
    }
});
```

Another solution would be just:

```
return WorkClassification.find({
    _id : {
        $in: this.classifications || []
    }
});
```

--

**Edit**: I just realize that the first solution would not be reactive in those cases (since the .find() would not be executed). However, I am not sure since I haven't tested it. Because of that, the best and safer solution would be only the second option.

Answer (score -1):

You can't do matching for id, you can apply it to search some field in record you have found, but not for record itself.

If `this.classifications` holds id use

`return WorkClassification.find({_id : this.classifications});`

Comment: I don't think that's right.  I'm getting this same error for a query that doesn't involve _id (and, I have successfully used a query like this for _id in the past).

Comment: As I said in my answer, the correct problem would be that this.classifications is undefined in some situations so $in fails because it expects the value be an array.